# Why my normal fonts won't load but the bold ones do

Tags: css, laravel, tailwind-css

What could be the possible reason why is that my other fonts cannot be loaded.
This is my fonts.css file

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
  src: url(../assets/fonts/sans/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf) format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  @apply .font-normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
  src: url(../assets/fonts/sans/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf) format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  @apply .font-light;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
  src: url(../assets/fonts/sans/SourceSansPro-SemiBold.ttf) format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  @apply .font-semibold;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
  src: url(../assets/fonts/sans/SourceSansPro-Italic.ttf) format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  @apply .font-normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
  src: url(../assets/fonts/sans/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf) format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  @apply .font-bold;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
  src: url(../assets/fonts/sans/SourceSansPro-Black.ttf) format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  @apply .font-black;
}
```

But the bold ones will only show up not the normal fonts

[image: Website test]

look at that only the black fonts load / bold ones..

[image]

Comment: I think it doesn't work like normal OSs. you need to define different `font-family` for every single font-file ( unless their same with different extensions). so here it seems it just loads the last declared font ( SourceSansPro-Black) and overloads it!

Comment: Right answer is here.

Comment: @MojtabaHn Defining a different `font-family` name is not the best solution, the way to do it is declaring different `font-weight` for the same `font-family` then the browser will do the job, more explanation at https://css-tricks.com/whats-deal-declaring-font-properties-font-face/

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the `font-weight` to have different font weights. The `@apply` rule seem to be ignored on `@font-face`. Try:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
  src: url(../assets/fonts/sans/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf) format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
  src: url(../assets/fonts/sans/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf) format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

and so on, I would recommend the following weight:

```
thin 100
extra-light 200
light 300
regular 400
medium 500
semi-bold 600
bold 700
extra-bold 800
black 900
```

Comment: Have you used tailwindcss before ? there's a fontweights object in the tailwind.js file.. that I've reffered to like in the ```@apply .font-normal ```.  Please know the code that I've posted first.

Comment: That is why I suggest you to define the `font-weight`... I am pretty sure the `@apply` rule is getting ignored on `@font-face`

Answer (score -1):

you have to use different `font-family` name for different font faces

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro normal";
  src: url(../assets/fonts/sans/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf) format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  @apply .font-normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro light";
  src: url(../assets/fonts/sans/SourceSansPro-Light.ttf) format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  @apply .font-light;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro semibold";
  src: url(../assets/fonts/sans/SourceSansPro-SemiBold.ttf) format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  @apply .font-semibold;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
  src: url(../assets/fonts/sans/SourceSansPro-Italic.ttf) format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  @apply .font-normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro bold";
  src: url(../assets/fonts/sans/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf) format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  @apply .font-bold;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro black";
  src: url(../assets/fonts/sans/SourceSansPro-Black.ttf) format("truetype");
  font-style: normal;
  @apply .font-black;
}
```

Comment: Don't need to use a different `font-family` name, the way to do it is declaring different `font-weight` for the same `font-family` then the browser will load the proper font.